# Strange allocation behavior in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In a form I am trying to keep several values in hidden fields:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Report", "Product", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id) // <-- sets always the Id of subsequent ProductId
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProductId)

    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Comment, 5)

    <input type="submit" value="@StringResources.Product_Report" class="btn" />
}
```

Regardless of which value is set in the `Id` field in the model, the value of `ProductId` property is set instead. When I stop the debugger on the first allocation of my snippet everything seems to be ok. But Firebugs shows me that the value of the `ProductId` property was taken over.

Since this is the second issue of this kind in my application I am thinking this is a bug in the framework. Or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you ad the code of your model class?

Comment: The (view-)model consists just of 4 simple public properties (string & long). No connection between.

Comment: Could you check inside of your controller what the value is there?

Comment: Yes I checked it already. For example in the controller the id is 0 (not persisted yet). If I stop the debugger on the allocation in the razor view the value is 0. In FireBug (and in the POST method) the value is 13 (= `ProductId`)

Comment: Do you have a Viewbag.ProductId in your action? The reason I ask this is because when a Viewbag is named the same as a property of a model class you do encounter issues simply because they all reside in FomrCollection and end up overwriting each other...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution. Here is an extact of my GET controller action:

```
public ActionResult Report(long id) // <-- this id is set in Razor
{
    var model = new ReportModel { ProductId = id };
    return View(model);
}
```

The parameter `id` in the method is rightly `productId`. The value of the `Id` property in Razor (`@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)`) was **overwritten by the method parameter**.

So the solution is simply:

```
public ActionResult Report(long productId)
{
    var model = new ReportModel { ProductId = productId };
    return View(model);
}
```

I didn't know that behavior and for me it looks still weird. Is this by design or a bug in the framework?